Understanding Prometheus Regex Relabeling
We are migrating our monitoring infrastructure to Prometheus.  We're using the prometheus-sd-exporter for Netbox to generate an http_sd_config to get scrape data.  Because of the way that nodes have been named in our Netbox instance, the generated __address__ label does not contain the FQDN which won't work for scrapes in our use case.  The generated __address__ label looks like:
__address__="host:9182"

We do have a custom field that contains the FQDN, __meta_netbox_custom_field_vm_dns, and I can relabel __address__ by concatenating the plugin-generated __address__ label with the FQDN field:
- source_labels: [__address__]
    regex: '.*([^:]\d\d\d+$).*'
    replacement: '$1'
    action: replace
    target_label: __tmp_port
- source_labels: [__meta_netbox_custom_field_vm_dns, __tmp_port]
    separator: ':'
    target_label: __address__

However this regex (which is working) confuses me as I don't understand why it needs the \d\d\d - based on this regex I think I should be able to get the port number without them.  I tried a number of iterations of this:
regex: '([^:]+$)' (gives http://host.example.com/metrics)
regex: '([^:]+$).*' (gives http://host.example.com/metrics)
regex: '.*([^:]+$)' (gives http://host.example.com:2/metrics)
regex: '.*([^:]+$).*' (gives http://host.example.com:2/metrics)
regex: '.*([^:]\d+$).*' (gives http://host.example.com:82/metrics)
regex: '.*([^:]\d\d+$).*' (gives http://host.example.com:182/metrics)
regex: '.*([^:]\d\d\d+$).*' (gives http://host.example.com:9182/metrics which is the correct value)

I'm wondering if there's something I'm doing wrong in the relabeling/regex process, as we would like this to work for an arbitrary port number and not one that is exactly four digits.
Does anyone have any insight as to why this is behaving this way or something I could do different?
Thanks!

In short: you need \d\d\d+ to match three digits at the end. [^:] matches first digit. I don't get how you've come to that regex, but it will only work for you if all ports you have are exactly four digits length. Use .*:(\d+$) instead.

Your suggested regex worked...thank you for the help.  I used the regex I had as we have some static configs that use a similar regex to get the value before the ":" and I thought it would just be possible to reverse that.  I guess I wasn't thinking things all the way through.
